# ¿Porqué margin-top:% desborda el contenido aunque se les sume el height de los otros elementos y sea este el height del body?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un body con un height:100% y dos divs de 50% que no se me desbordan, pero ahora quiero ponerle a uno de los divs un margin-top:0.5%, el problema es que se me desborda aunque le reste -0.5% a alguno de los divs, y no entiendo porque? Si la suma de todos los porcentajes sigue siendo la altura del body.

```css
html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
}
div{
width:100%;
}
#uno{
height:50%;
background-color:blue;
}
#dos{
height:49.5%;
background-color:purple;
margin-top:0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
```

Porque pasa esto? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque el `%` es una unidad relativa, es decir su valor depende de otro elemento.

##### ¿Relativa a quien?

Es relativa al `width` de la caja, no importado si es `bottom` o `top`, es siempre al width

De la [documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
> generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
> 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
> width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
> in CSS 2.1.

Esto lo puedes comprobar facilmente

- A `uno` y `dos` le damos un anchura de `10px`
- Luego a `dos` un `margin-top` del `100%`

Esto debería generar un espacio **cuadrado** de lado "10px" entre los 2 div, tal como se muestra en el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
#padre{
height:100%;
width:10px;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
}
div{
width:100%;
}
#uno{
height:50%;
background-color:blue;
}
#dos{
height:49%;
background-color:purple;
margin-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
</div>
```

---

Una posible solución, para lograr el efecto deseado es que `dos` tenga `position:absolute` y le das un `top:50.5%`

```css
html, body{
height:100%;
width:10px;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
inset:0
}
div{
 width:100%;
}
#uno{
 height:50%;
 background-color:blue;
}
#dos{
 height:49.5%;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:purple;
 top:50.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
```